# How can I send the output of an AWK script to a file?

Tags: awk

Within an AWK script, I'm needing to send the output of the script to a file while also printing it to the terminal. Is there a nice and tidy way I can do this without having a copy of every print redirect to the file?

I'm not particularly good at making SSCCE examples but here's my attempt at demonstrating my problem;

```
BEGIN{
    print "This is an awk script"
    
    # I don't want to have to do this for every print
    print "This is an awk script" > thisiswhack.out
}

{
    # data manip. stuff here
    # ...
    print "%s %s %s" blah, blah blah
    
    # I don't want to have to do this for every print again
    print "%s %s %s" blah blah blah >> thisiswhack.out
}

END{
    print "Yay we're done!"
    
    # Seriously, there has to be a better way to do this within the script
    print "Yay we're done!" >> thisiswhack.out
}
```

Surely there must be a way to send the entire output of the script to an output file **within the script itself**, right?

Comment: You can use a function in awk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to duplicate streams is `tee`, and we can use it inside awk:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {tee = "tee out.txt"}
    {print | tee}' in.txt
```

- This invokes `tee` with the file argument `out.txt`, and opens a stream to this command.
- The stream (and therefore `tee`) remains open until awk exits, or `close(tee)` is called.
- Every time `print | tee` is used, the data is printed to that stream. `tee` then appends this data both to the file `out.txt`, and stdout.
- The `| command` feature is POSIX awk. Also the `tee` variable isn't compulsory (you can use the string).
- Of course, we can use tee outside awk too: `awk ... | tee out.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

GNU `AWK`'s [Redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html) allows sending output to command, rather than file, therefore I suggest following exploit of said feature:

```
awk 'BEGIN{command="tee output.txt"}{print tolower($0) | command}' input.txt
```

Note: I use `tolower($0)` for demonstration purposes. I redirect print into [`tee`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tee) command, which does output to mentioned file and standard output, thus you should get lowercase version of `input.txt` written to `output.txt` and standard output.

If you are not confined to single `awk` usage then you might alternatively use `tee` outside, like so

```
awk '{print tolower($0)}' input.txt | tee output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
    function prtf(str) {
        printf "%s", str > "thisiswhack.out"
        printf "%s", str
        fflush()
    }
    function prt(str) {
        prtf( str ORS )
    }
    {
        # to print adding a newline at the end:
        prt( "foo" )

        # to print as-is without adding a newline:
        prtf( sprintf("%s, %s, %d", $2, "bar", 17) )
    }
' file
```

In the above we are not spawning a subshell to call any other command so it's efficient, and we're using `fflush()` after every print to ensure both output streams (stdout and the extra file) don't get out of sync with respect to each other (e.g. stdout displays less text than the file or vice-versa if the command is killed).

The above always overwrites the contents of "thisiswhack.out" with whatever the script outputs. If you want to append instead then change `>` to `>>`. If you want the option of doing both, introduce a variable (which I've named `prtappend` below) to control it which you can set on the command line, e.g. change:

```
    printf "%s", str > "thisiswhack.out"
```

to:

```
    printf "%s", str >> "thisiswhack.out"
```

and add:

```
    BEGIN {
        if ( !prtappend ) {
            printf "" > "thisiswhack.out"
        }
    }
```

then if you do `awk -v prtappend=1 '...'` it'll append to `thisiswhack.out` instead of overwriting it.

Of course, the better approach if you're on a Unix system is to have your awk script called from a shell script with it's output piped to `tee`, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    {
        print "foo"

        printf"%s, %s, %d", $2, "bar", 17 
    }
' "${@:--}" |
tee 'thisiswhack.out'
```

Note that this is one more example of why you should not call awk from a shebang.